# ImagePad up to AspectRatio

Tags: image-processing, image

I cannot come up with idiomatic Mathematica code to solve this simple problem:

1. take: image and desired aspect ratio

   1. get image dimensions
   2. upsize the dimensions to desired aspect ratio
2. return`{{left, right}, {bottom, up}}` for `ImagePad`

---

https://www.instagram.com/p/CMxh05OH4Ss/ (⬅️ needed the answer for these)

Comment: for (1) you can use [ImageAspectRatio](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAspectRatio.html)

Comment: @kglr I know but I am struggling to get the second argument to ImagePad calculated o__O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with this:

```
pad // ClearAll
pad[i_Image, r_] := pad[ImageDimensions@i, r]
pad[d_, r_] := Module[{n, w, h},
  n = Max[d]/Max[r]*Min[r];
  {w, h} = Clip[(n - d)/2, {0, \[Infinity]}];
  {w, h} {{1, 1}, {1, 1}} // Round
  ]
```

---

To answer the request for an example photo:

```
i = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GmI2.png" // Import
r = {4, 5} (* {w, h} = instagram portrait aspect ratio *)
ImagePad[i, i~pad~r, "Fixed"]
```

Before padding
[image]

After padding
[image]

Comment: do you mind adding an example input(s) showing  the connection to  image aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[pad2]
pad2[i_Image, ar_] := Module[{d = ImageDimensions @ i},
  Round[{#, #}/2] & /@ Ramp[Max[d] Min[ar, 1/ar] - d]]

ImagePad[i, pad2[i, 4/5], "Fixed"]
```

[image]

```
ImagePad[#, pad2[#, 4/5], "Fixed"] & @ ImageRotate[i, Pi/2]
```

[image]

Comment: This does feel more idiomatic! Sweet use of `Ramp` and `4/5`. Obviously, I was not posting the above receipt to Instagram but (helping post) a watercolor painting by my wife : https://www.instagram.com/p/CMxh05OH4Ss/

Comment: @CetinSert, wonderful pictures!

Answer (score 1):

Would the following do?

```
pad[im_Image, r : {w_, h_}] := 
 Module[{idim = ImageDimensions[im], 
   ratim = Divide @@ ImageDimensions[im], rat = Divide @@ r, pad},
  If[ratim < rat
   , pad = Round[ (idim[[2]] rat - idim[[1]])/2]; 
   ImagePad[im, {{pad, pad}, {0, 0}}, "Fixed"]
   , pad = Round[ (idim[[1]] /rat - idim[[2]])/2]; 
   ImagePad[im, {{0, 0}, {pad, pad}}, "Fixed"]
   ]
  ]

t = pad[i, {4, 5}]
```

Comment: I guess so (not a fan of the explicit `If` though, feels too C-ish) but I also believe something a lot shorter than both of our answers must be possible with a language like Mathematica.

Comment: It is sort of a game to produce the shortest code. But it is often very cryptical and the ideas behind are well hidden.